# Add memoization to a recursively defined haskell function

Tags: haskell, recursion, memoization

I've solved a dynamic programming problem in Haskell (actually a Project Euler problem) with what boils down to a generalisation of the Fibonacci sequence:

```
 f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)
 g(n) = g(n-1) + g(n-3)
 h(n) = h(n-1) + h(n-4)
```

There are a few more functions like this, and because of the size of the problem, I've had to add memoization, which is pretty trivial, like so:

```
memF = (map f' [0 ..] !!)
  where f' x | x <=1 = 1
        f' 2         = 2
        f' x         = memF(x-1) + memF(x-2)


memG = (map f' [0 ..] !!)
  where f' x | x <=2 = 1
        f' 3         = 2
        f' x         = memG(x-1) + memG(x-3)
```

This works fine, so I can get the answer as `(memF 100) + (memG 100) + ...` and I've answered the question, but the repeated code is ugly, and I'd rather define a single function to generate the memoized functions, so something like:

```
mem d = (map f' [0 ..] !!)
  where f' x | x < d  = 1
        f' x | x == d = 2
        f' x          = (mem d) (x-1) + (mem d)(x-d)
```

And then answer as `mem 2 100 + mem 3 100 + ...` This fails, or at least the caching doesn't work, I guess because the array is recreated with each call, I suppose I could use the StateMonad or a memoization library, but I'd be interested to know if there is a way to do this without Monads.  Is there please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need another binding to avoid the recursive call to `mem d`:

```
mem d = g
  where g = (map f' [0 ..] !!)
        f' x | x < d  = 1
        f' x | x == d = 2
        f' x          = g (x-1) + g (x-d)
```

Also be careful when you are calling `mem`, since each call to `mem` will create its own cache. E.g.

```
mem 10 x + mem 10 y
```

will not cache anything, while

```
let g = mem 10 in g x + g y
```

will use the same cache.

An alternative could be to use a single "global" cache for all the calls `mem d x`, using memoization on the pair `(d,x)`. This looks a bit more tricky to achieve, though.

Comment: OK that works, thank you: so the binding captures the function call and delta value.  Nice.

Comment: @user118165 Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: The global cache is an interesting idea -- I guess you'd use a map?  Of course as you point out it doesn't add much in this case.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user118165 I'm not sure about what I would use right now. `Data.Map.Map` is strict, so that can not be used. We need a lazy data structure.